# How to create attached topic modeling visualization?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, visualization, topic-modeling

I found the attached image at https://www.kdnuggets.com/2018/08/topic-modeling-lsa-plsa-lda-lda2vec.html . It is showing visualization of topic modeling results. Which tool is used to create such visualization? Any guidance on how to create it?

[topic modeling vizualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3AWV.png)

Answer (score 2):

They have extracted some of the info from a trained topic model, and reshaped it into a graph (network) form. It looks like they've taken the most strongly associated words from each topic in their model as one set of nodes in the graph, and also added a node for each individual topic and given it a label themselves based on what they think the topic is about.

My guess is that the edges (connections) between the term nodes and the topic nodes are weighted by the term to topic score developed by the model. They've probably filtered out low scores which is why there are only edges between terms and one or two topics (whilst in topic modelling every term has some score associated with each topic).

To visualise the graph it looks like they've used Gephi which is an open source graph visualisation tool. They've likely used a force atlas 2 layout to distribute the nodes, coloured the nodes by modularity class (which can be calculated in gephi) and manually sized the topic nodes as larger than the term nodes.

In terms of actually producing such a thing, the creation of the graph representation can be done using the networkx package. There are plenty of tutorials around on how to work with networkx.

Once you've created the networkx graph object that contains the structure I described above, you can export it to `.gexf`format which can be opened by gephi for you to do the final stage of visualising. Again, online tutorials should be available for doing these kinds of things in Gephi.